# Группировка элементов по дате дочернего массива

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Возможно ли сгруппировать по дате (createDate) в дочернем массиве? Нужно что бы была основная запись (она будет дублироваться много раз, если дата будет разная) и дочерние элементы с одной датой. Хочу вывести красиво на страницу по датам создания, что бы была основная запись и при раскрытии блока выводились записи из **computerEvents**. Ключом в бд является createDate и id
Мне прилетают данные с сервера в виде:

```
   {
        "maC_Address": "F4:B5:20:35:40:8E",
        "iP_Address": "100.105.15.19",
        "name_PC": "GH-440",
        "bridge": "BridgeSTD",
        "status": 0,
        "components": [],
        "computerEvents": [
            {
                "id": "bf49932c-522f-40e1-b3aa-958245e57b81",
                "computerId": "F4:B5:20:35:40:8E",
                "createDate": "2023-03-15T05:28:29.004484Z",
                "description": "ChannelA-DIMM0 RAM: 8192 Mbyte",
                "event": 0,
                "type": 4
            },
            {
                "id": "3f11ac8b-5e14-4687-9bc8-89b3e7e96079",
                "computerId": "F4:B5:20:35:40:8E",
                "createDate": "2023-03-15T05:28:29.004483Z",
                "description": "Базовый видеоадаптер (Майкрософт)",
                "event": 0,
                "type": 0
            },
            {
                "id": "e875dc2b-d5cd-4630-ad42-8187ea0712a3",
                "computerId": "F4:B5:20:35:40:8E",
                "createDate": "2023-03-15T05:28:29.004484Z",
                "description": "U3E1 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-9100 CPU @ 3.60GHz",
                "event": 0,
                "type": 3
            },
            {
                "id": "28c7fcba-3b78-4933-8315-3ba4fb94ab6e",
                "computerId": "F4:B5:20:35:40:8E",
                "createDate": "2023-03-15T05:28:29.004484Z",
                "description": "BIOS Date: 11/27/20 14:20:28 Ver: 05.0000C",
                "event": 0,
                "type": 1
            },
            {
                "id": "5bc5930d-a988-4d0e-bccb-22d2e43db01d",
                "computerId": "F4:B5:20:35:40:8E",
                "createDate": "2023-03-15T05:28:29.004484Z",
                "description": "H310MHP",
                "event": 0,
                "type": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "maC_Address": "F4:B5:20:35:40:D7",
        "iP_Address": "100.105.22.2",
        "name_PC": "GD-230",
        "bridge": "BridgeSTD",
        "status": 0,
        "components": [],
        "computerEvents": [
            {
                "id": "3c3c040f-0394-4aae-825d-9c90337be5ef",
                "computerId": "F4:B5:20:35:40:D7",
                "createDate": "2023-03-20T03:21:52.689966Z",
                "description": "U3E1 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-9100 CPU @ 3.60GHz",
                "event": 0,
                "type": 3
            },
            {
                "id": "ccfb3619-9b08-49f0-a191-5454feac496c",
                "computerId": "F4:B5:20:35:40:D7",
                "createDate": "2023-03-20T03:21:52.689547Z",
                "description": "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti",
                "event": 0,
                "type": 0
            },
            {
                "id": "dbe3eb8f-5c18-4585-b8f6-4c26218deafa",
                "computerId": "F4:B5:20:35:40:D7",
                "createDate": "2023-03-20T03:21:52.689965Z",
                "description": "5.12",
                "event": 0,
                "type": 1
            },
            {
                "id": "313801d2-98f9-4939-b784-741ad06d5e95",
                "computerId": "F4:B5:20:35:40:D7",
                "createDate": "2023-03-20T03:21:52.689966Z",
                "description": "H310MHP",
                "event": 0,
                "type": 2
            },
            {
                "id": "0bd01695-c620-41eb-84cc-4373bccf53cc",
                "computerId": "F4:B5:20:35:40:D7",
                "createDate": "2023-03-20T03:21:52.689967Z",
                "description": "ChannelA-DIMM0 RAM: 8192 Mbyte",
                "event": 0,
                "type": 4
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Возможно ли сгруппировать по дате (createDate) в дочернем массиве?

Могу предложить такой вариант группировки по дате...

```js
const obj = {
  "maC_Address": "00:aa:00:64:c8:09",
  "iP_Address": "100.150.1.25",
  "name_PC": "GH_554",
  "bridge": "STD",
  "status": 0,
  "computerEvents": [
      {
          "id": "3c3c040f-0394-4aae-825d-9c90337be5ef",
          "computerId": "00:aa:00:64:c8:09",
          "createDate": "2023-03-20T03:21:52.689966Z",
          "description": "U3E1 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-9100 CPU @ 3.60GHz",
          "event": 0,
          "type": 3
      },
      {
          "id": "ccfb3619-9b08-49f0-a191-5454feac496c",
          "computerId": "00:aa:00:64:c8:09",
          "createDate": "2023-03-20T03:21:52.689547Z",
          "description": "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti",
          "event": 0,
          "type": 0
      },
      {
          "id": "dbe3eb8f-5c18-4585-b8f6-4c26218deafa",
          "computerId": "F4:B5:20:35:40:D7",
          "createDate": "2023-03-21T03:21:52.689965Z",
          "description": "5.12",
          "event": 0,
          "type": 1
      },
      {
          "id": "313801d2-98f9-4939-b784-741ad06d5e95",
          "computerId": "00:aa:00:64:c8:09",
          "createDate": "2023-03-20T03:21:52.689966Z",
          "description": "H310MHP",
          "event": 0,
          "type": 2
      },
      {
          "id": "0bd01695-c620-41eb-84cc-4373bccf53cc",
          "computerId": "00:aa:00:64:c8:09",
          "createDate": "2023-03-22T03:21:52.689967Z",
          "description": "ChannelA-DIMM0 RAM: 8192 Mbyte",
          "event": 0,
          "type": 4
      }
  ]
}
obj.list = list(obj.computerEvents)
console.log(obj.list)
//
function list(arr) {
  const m = new Map()
  return arr.reduce((a, o) => {
    const d = o.createDate.split('T')[0]
    const i = m.has(d) ? m.get(d) : a.length
    if (!a[i]) {
      a[i] = {date: d, info: []}
      m.set(d, i)
    }
    a[i].info.push(o)
    return a
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: Почти что нужно, но нужно что бы в info была основная запись ( с полями maC_Address, iP_Address, name_PC и т.д ) и в нём был computerEvents в котором содержаться записи сгруппированные по дате

Comment: @ПоедательПитсы, я тебе показал как такое можно сгруппировать... А в какие поля все это пихать - уже можешь реализовать самостоятельно. ;)